# Split a string at the beginning and end of words

Tags: python, split

I have a string like this:

```
"hello world   foo  bar"
```

And I want to split it at the beginning and end of words, like this:

```
["hello", " ", "world", "   ", "foo", "  ", "bar"]
```

Comment: And have you tried.. anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `re.split()` function:

```
import re

s = 'hello world   foo  bar'
result = re.split(r'(\s+)', s)
print(result)
```

The output:

```
['hello', ' ', 'world', '   ', 'foo', '  ', 'bar']
```

- `(\s+)` - when used in `re.split()` function pattern split the input string by the occurrences of pattern `\s+` (one or more whitespace characters). If capturing parentheses `(...)` are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.split

---

Or the same result with `re.findall()` function:

```
result = re.findall(r'\S+|\s+', s)
```

- `\S+|\s+` - regexp alternation group; capture both non-whitespace `\S+` and whitespace `\s+` character sequences as separate items of the resulting list

Comment: I'm sure OP can copy paste that, but it didn't teach them anything.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, you have my explanation